# Proving continuity of the function $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}} $

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Using only the epsilon delta criterion, show that the function $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}} $ is continuous over its entire domain of definition.

Definition of the epsilon delta criterion:

A function $f$ from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous at a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R} $ if given $ε > 0$ there exists $δ > 0$ such that if $|x-x_0| < \delta $ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|< \epsilon$.

I have already started looking for delta, but get stuck here, and don't know how to further transform or estimate to find the appropriate delta:

$ \begin{aligned}\left|f(x)-f\left(x_{0}\right)\right| &=\left|\frac{x^{3}}{1+x^{2}}-\frac{x_{0}^{3}}{1+x_{0}^{2}}\right|=\\ &=\left|\frac{x^{3}\left(1+x_{0}^{2}\right)}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x_{0}^{2}\right)}-\frac{x_{0}^{3}\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{\left(1+x_{0}^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{2}\right)}\right|=\\ &=\left|\frac{x^{3}\left(1+x_{0}^{2}\right)-x_{0}^{3}\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x_{0}^{2}\right)}\right|=?\end{aligned} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
|x^3(1+y^2)- y^3(1+x^2)| & = |(x-y)(x^2+x y + y^2 + x^2 y^2)|\\
&\le |x-y|(x^2 + \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2) + y^2 + x^2 y^2)\\
&\le \frac{3}{2}|x-y|(x^2 + y^2 + x^2 y^2)\\
&\le \frac{3}{2}|x-y|(1 + x^2)(1+y^2)\\
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{|x^3(1+y^2)- y^3(1+x^2)|}{(1 + x^2)(1+y^2)}
\le \frac{\frac{3}{2}|x-y|(1 + x^2)(1+y^2)}{(1 + x^2)(1+y^2)}
\le\frac{3}{2}|x-y|
\end{equation}

Hence
\begin{equation}
|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le \frac{3}{2} |x-x_0|
\end{equation}

Comment: What did you do with the denominator? Did you estimate it upwards somehow?

Comment: @clementine1001 See my edits above.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}-\frac{x_0^3}{1+x_0^2}=(x-x_0)\left(\dfrac{xx_0-1}{(1+x^2)(1+x_0^2)}+1\right).$$

Clearly, the right factor is bounded, for any $x_0$, as the denominator has no root and its degree exceeds that of the numerator.

---

> As $\left|\dfrac x{x^2+1}\right|$ is bounded by $\frac12$ and $\dfrac1{x^2+1}$ by $1$, the factor is bounded by $\dfrac{\frac12|x_0|+1}{1+x_0^2}+1$, itself bounded by $\frac12\frac12+1+1$. Hence, convergence is uniform.

Comment: Yves, I'm just curious, what happened to your old account and its many fine answers? (If you'd rather not answer, just let me know and I'll delete this.)

Comment: @BarryCipra: I deleted my account and started another, for personal reasons. The answers remain under a user number. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Curiously, your current account says you've been a member for four days, but its list of "newest posts" includes two answers from several years ago. Have you mastered time travel?

Comment: @BarryCipra: haha, that's right. Possibly the real parts of imaginary dates...

Comment: The next step will be to post answers to questions that haven't been asked yet. I can hardly wait!

Comment: @BarryCipra: $2^1+2^3+2^5$. ;-)

Comment: I'll give that calculation some deep thought....

Comment: @BarryCipra: possibly by deep learning...